# Transpose VBA Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm required to upload excel B to SQL database. But the users only managed to provide the format in excel A due to some reasons. Therefore, I need a transpose method to convert excel A into excel B so that my upload can be done.

Here are the format for excel A and B.
Excel A **(user provided)**

```
AREA    CATEGORY    202033  202034  202035  202036
WET     FISH          33      34      35      36
WET     CHICKEN       36      35      34      33
DRY     VEGETABLES    34      28      24      24
```

Excel B **(required format to upload to SQL database)**

```
AREA     CATEGORY       WEEK    SALES
WET      FISH          202033    33
WET      FISH          202034    34
WET      FISH          202035    35
WET      FISH          202036    36
WET      CHICKEN       202033    36
WET      CHICKEN       202034    35
WET      CHICKEN       202035    34
WET      CHICKEN       202036    33
DRY      VEGETABLES    202033    34
DRY      VEGETABLES    202034    28
DRY      VEGETABLES    202035    24
DRY      VEGETABLES    202036    24
```

I'm totally new to VBA excel macro but I need to get this completed. Anyone can guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub test()

    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim toWs As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    Dim j As Integer, c As Integer
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet 'set your Orginal data sheet
    Set toWs = Sheets(2) 'set Result sheet
    
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)
    
    For i = 2 To r
        For j = 3 To c
            If vDB(i, j) <> "" Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 4, 1 To n)
                vR(1, n) = vDB(i, 1)
                vR(2, n) = vDB(i, 2)
                vR(3, n) = vDB(1, j)
                vR(4, n) = vDB(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    With toWs
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Range("a1").Resize(1, 4) = Array("AREA", "CATEGORY", "WEEK", "SALES")
        .Range("a2").Resize(n, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @TinMan, `For i = 2 To r` is right. But `vR(3, n) = vDB(1, j)` is right.

Comment: You are right.  I think that I ran my first results to the same sheet and was missing the week numbers.  Anyway, your code works great now.

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't answer this post because there the OP has provided no coding examples.  But the OP did make an effort to write an otherwise good post and I'm quite bored.

```
Sub ConvertUserData()
    Const SourceWorksheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const HeaderColumnCount As Long = 2
    Dim Data As Variant
    
    Data = Worksheets(SourceWorksheetName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim RowCount As Long
    RowCount = (UBound(Data, 2) - HeaderColumnCount) * (UBound(Data) - 1)
    
    Dim Results() As Variant
    ReDim Results(1 To RowCount, 1 To 4)
   
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim Column As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Row = 2 To UBound(Data)
        For Column = HeaderColumnCount + 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            n = n + 1
            Results(n, 1) = Data(Row, 1)
            Results(n, 2) = Data(Row, 2)
            Results(n, 3) = Data(1, Column)
            Results(n, 4) = Data(Row, Column)
        Next
    Next
   
    With Workbooks.Add
        With Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("AREA", "CATEGORY", "WEEK", "SALES")
        .Range("A2").Resize(RowCount, 4) = Results
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```